# Socket Io : send file from node server to python client

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, sendfile

As I quoted in the title, I want to send files from my server node to my client python using socket io. I searched for some examples to send files from a browser client to node server like this https://github.com/rico345100/socket.io-file-example. It works and now I need to send the file uploaded on the server to the python client.

I have already maintained a socket io connection between python and node . Any idea about which method should I use? Is there an example to follow ?

Comment: Please share whatever code you've written so far. Stackoverflow is not a "Free-Code-Writing-Service".